# How to host downloadable ZIP file?

Tags: magento2, htaccess, download

I have a ZIP file. I want it so when a user clicks a link on a page, it will download the ZIP file.

I have the ZIP under pub/media/downloadable and inside there's a .htaccess file, and currently this is the content inside:

```
<IfVersion < 2.4>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</IfVersion>
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
    Require all denied
</IfVersion>

AddType application/octet-stream .zip
```

And the link on my page is this:

```
<a href="/pub/media/downloadable/zipfile.zip">Download ZIP Here</a>
```

But clicking on the link simply redirects to `/pub/media/downloadable/zipfile.zip` instead of downloading, which brings a 404.

== **UPDATE** ==

To make the link downloadable, all I had to do was add the `download` attribute to the `<a>`, like this:

`<a href="/pub/media/downloadable/zipfile.zip" download >Download ZIP Here</a>`

However, when I tried to download it, Google Chrome said "Failed - No File". The path is correct and the file is there, with permissions 644.

Comment: Can you please upload the file code where this link available?

Comment: Where you added link (phtml/cms page) ?

Comment: Is your shop running in a subdirectory?

Comment: @RohanHapani I have this link in a CMS page.

Comment: @Pawan See above comment.

Comment: @simonthesorcerer I'm not sure what you mean. I have multiple stores under one Magento configuration, so I would assume the stores are split into subdirectories. However, the Magento installation is under root directory, not a subdirectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a proper solution or an explanation why this works, but all I did was move the ZIP file to `pub/media` directory and it worked. The lines in the `.htaccess` file did not do anything.

All that's needed is the `download` attribute on the anchor.